# Extract Href value from specific div class using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a google chrome extension. 
I extracted the source code of the webpage using a jquery get function in the following way:

```
$.get(link,function(data){
 //From this the entire source code of the link will be available in the variable data
 };
```

The html source will be of this format

```
<div class="DivClass">  
    <img src="2.jpg" width="100" />
    <span class="time_date">FEBRUARY 19, 2014</span>
    <h3><a title="Title" href="213.html">Title</a></h3>
</div>
```

I wanted a way to extract the href link within the divclass named DivClass.
I tried the following way:

```
var links=[];
$(data).find('#DivClass').each(function(){
                    links.push($(this).attr('href'));               
                });
```

I used links as an array, as there can be multiple instances of the specific divclass. Could someone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: Use a `.` and not a `#` for classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use class selectors. So use `.DivClass` instead of `#DivClass` and You need to target anchor thus change your selectors to `$(data).find('.DivClass a')`

Use

```
var links = [];
$(data).find('.DivClass a').each(function () {
    links.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using id selector (`#`) for class (`.`)

```
$(data).find('.DivClass a').each(function(){
    links.push($(this).attr('href'));               
});
```

Comment: Thanks It is working! I am sorry I cannot upvote you, as everyone here answered the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the `#DivClass` is not the link. Try this:

```
var links=[];
$(data).find('.DivClass a').each(function(){
                links.push($(this).attr('href'));               
            });
```

Comment: Thanks It is working! I am sorry I cannot upvote you, as everyone here answered the same :)